# How to use setMute() in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Tried searching about mute commands, but they were all role based and as I understand setMute is what i need. Which is to mute a specific member without having to mess with any roles, just can't figure how to use the command as anything i try it's either not a function or something is undefined. This is what i have now

```
let person = message.Client.users.fetch('id');
    let reason = ''
    person.then(function(personuser) {

            personuser.setMute(true, reason);
    });
```

Comment: Where does your understanding of setMute come from? There is a setMute to mute members in voice channels, but that doesn't seem like what you're looking for. Are you actually trying to [timeout a member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout)?

Comment: I know it mutes a member in voice channel, that's about it. The command I'm making  is supposed to mute the same member everytime. The point is to enable anyone with perms to use this command, it's for private server

Answer (score 0):

To mute someone, fetch him as a "Guild Member", not "User".

```
message.guild?.members.fetch("userid").then(member => {
    const reason = "reason"
    member.voice.setMute(true, reason);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want roles, you can just use time out.

```js
const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);
const time = 60; // Duration for timeout in milliseconds
const reason = 'Deserved it?' // reason for timeout if you have one
await member.timeout(time, reason);
```

timeouts are handy. u dont have to keep a db for finding out when to unmute/remove role from a user. discord does it for you.